# Android application is being blocked from restarting by MARsPolicyManager

Tags: android, samsung-galaxy, samsung-knox

An Android function (APP A in the log) sent alerts to another application (APP B in the log).
We are facing one issue. APP B application is being blocked from restarting by MARsPolicyManager because of an autorun policy.
In Samsung S8, Smart Manager application is available. This application optimizes the device and kills the unnecessary background application from the device.
Below are the ADB logs:

```
05-30 01:03:33.481  1592  2291 D MARsPolicyManager: Blocked by Policy:2 -- Caller is not samsung!!
05-30 01:03:33.481  1592  2291 D MARsPolicyManager: Package: com.nielsen.appb, userid: 0, hostingType: provider is Restricted by policy: autorun(2) caller is: ProcessRecord{7da5e2d0 11579:com.nielsen.appa/u0a207}
05-30 01:03:33.482  1592  1654 I ActivityManager: Displayed com.nielsen.appa/md5ddf5d0d55652744930eac3d8d34aaa0c.SurveyPerform: +209ms
05-30 01:03:33.482 11579 11579 E ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.nielsen.qct.contentprovider.EventsProvider
05-30 01:03:33.492  1592  2291 D EdgeLightingManager: isCallingUserSupported : callingUserId=0, mUserId=0, isDualAppId=false
05-30 01:03:33.492  1592  2291 D EdgeLightingManager: showForToast : packageName = com.nielsen.appa
05-30 01:03:33.492  1592  2291 D EdgeLightingClientManager: isAvailableEdgeLighting: condition=1 mCondition=3 mIsConnected=false0
05-30 01:03:33.492  1592  2291 D EdgeLightingPolicyManager: isAcceptableApplication:  pkg=com.nielsen.appa
 , range=512 , includeAllApp=false , userId=0 , infoRange=0 , infoCategory=0
05-30 01:03:33.492  1592  2291 D EdgeLightingManager: showForToast : return false by isAcceptableApplication.
```

When the app is force stopped all notifications are removed from the notification shade. Force stop / force killed also means the app can't receive any push notifications or any other Intents while the app is in this state.

The device is:

Samsung Galaxy S8
Model No-SM G9500
Android 8,9.
Processor- Snapdragon

This device model only available in the United States and China.

We need your support here. We have a couple of questions as well.

1. What the MARsPolicyManager is?
2. Is it something related to KNOX ?
3. How we can avoid this issue ?
4. Is this android specific ?

Comment: I am wondering the same on an Samsung Galaxy A8 model SM-A530F Android version 9.  If you found the answer I would be very happy if you reply to your question.